# How to create Eloquent query from request with OR and AND conditions in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I send in this JSON object to the API endpoint:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "city": "Berlin",
    },
    {
        "name": "Jack",
        "country": "USA",
    }
]
```

I want to create this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
  (`name` = "John" AND `city` = "Berlin")
  OR
  (`name` = "Jack" AND `country` = "USA");
```

I have a `User` model to handle users.

What is the most simpliest way to create this SQL query with Laravel Eloquent query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return User::orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->where('name', 'John')->where('city', 'Berlin');
    })->orWhere(function (Builder $query) {
        return $query->where('name', 'Jack')->where('country', 'USA');
    })->get();
```

(edit) If you want to send parameter(s);

```
$city = 'Berlin';
$country = 'USA';

return User::orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($city) {
        return $query->where('name', 'John')->where('city', $city);
    })->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($country) {
        return $query->where('name', 'Jack')->where('country', $country);
    })->get();
```

If you want to generate it dynamically;

```
public function index()
{
    $parameters = [
        [
            'name' => 'John',
            'city' => 'Berlin',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Jack',
            'country' => 'USA',
        ]
    ];

    $query = User::query();

    foreach ($parameters as $item) {
        $query->orWhere(function (Builder $query) use ($item) {
            foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }
        });
    }

    return $query->get();
}
```

Comment: All data in the request are parameters. The only sure point is if the array has multiple items it will be an `OR` condition and the array item's property will be `AND` condition in an `OR` condition.

Comment: @netdjw you want each individual json block to be in separate `or` condition. Inside that condition each key/value pair will be `and`ed with respective column key/values right ?

Comment: This answer is exactly satisfies what you want @netdjw

Comment: @netdjw i am not sure whether i get it right, i added another possible solution.